# How to use redis for calculate uniq users?

Tags: redis

I have 2 params in log file:

```
timestamp, ip.
```

What is the best way to calculate number of uniq ip per minute for example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this excellent blog post that suggests solutions to your problem:

http://chris6f.com/rate-limiting-with-redis